# Solution for moving SVN from branch to trunk

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am attempting to use a `git svn` clone to move my SVN repo over to Git, whilst preserving the history. I know that Git SVN clone works for me as I have tried it with a simple test SVN repo.

The problem that I have is that the SVN repo does not have a trunk directory and all of the code is in a `/branch` directory (not `/branches`). `git svn clone` is returning an error as no `/trunk` directory is available.

So my question is, how do I move the content in my SVN `/branch` directory into `/trunk` whilst preserving the history?

Comment: I added `git` tag.... first, it matches... second, it will be read by a lot more people than by just using `git-svn` (I picked it up because I am keeping an eye on `svn` out of curiosity as well).

Comment: Try `git svn clone --trunk=/branch` , no `--tags`, no `--branches`, no `-s`/`--stdlayout`.

Comment: Do you want to move *branch* to *trunk* using svn? That would be `svn mv ^/branch ^/trunk` and it will preserve history.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *default* layout for `git init` (which I think is the default in `git-svn`, though I might be wrong on that assumption), then `git-svn` will fail if that is not the case.... however, you can pinpoint separate branches by using `-T` or `--trunk` when calling `git svn init`. Check https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn

Comment: Thanks for the answer eftshift0, I should indeed have spent more time with the svn documentation. This is a one off change so shouldn't have to repeat. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed this in the end by following the combined advice posted by everyone above. Thanks very much.

I removed all of the flags that are suggested in the documentation and managed to get hold of my /branch directory by including that in the URI. This worked for me as I'm not actually including any branches or tags, so it's quite simple. A more complex svn structure would be a different kettle of fish.

```
git svn clone https://uri/svn/branch
```